Avoid using a service account JSON on GCP with Polars
I'm trying to read a parquet file on GCP that lives on GCS using Polars. I'm running into an error when I try pl.read_parquet("gs://...") or pl.scan_parquet("gs://...") - Polars complains that it cannot read the service account JSON file because it does not exist. I do have an environment variable with the service account, but it is just an email address, not a path to a JSON file. Due to company policy, I am unable to get a JSON file.
I was hoping Polars wouldn't ask me for a JSON service account from version 1.10 onward when I provide a credential_provider argument to the read / scan functions but it still does.
I would like to avoid having to use pyarrow in the middle because it didn't work well for me in the past in a multiprocessing context. The workaround I'm using for now is to download the parquets to the local file system first with gsutil, but this is a bit cumbersome.

QQ here, what you have available in the env, what is it exactly? Just an email address? Or is it the whole credentials JSON?

@EdoAkse just an email address that ends with iam.gserviceaccount.com.

I'd take a look at the implementation of the CredentialProviderGCP and check if you can obtain valid credentials using the google.auth package.

You'll need more than just an email address in any case. Otherwise I could just use the same emailaddress in my own app and access all your stuff. This article describes the steps used in authentication

Yes, that I understand. The question is more about how to tell Polars not to use the JSON file now that the credential_provider argument exists.
